# Generate a set of n = 100 X = {xi}, i = 1,… n, xi ∈ R^2 within an ellipse in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, geometry

The full question is Generate a set of n = 100 points, X = {xi}, i = 1,… n, xi ∈ R^2 within an ellipse (x − μx)^2/a^2 + (y − μy)^2/b^2 centered at [μx, μy] = [5, −5] and has a major axis 2a = 10 and minor axis 2b = 5
Scatter plot all the points in Python. I am stuck on a problem. How could I plot n = 100 points within an ellipse?

Comment: Using `matplotlib` is is a good start, specifically `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then either `plt.plot` or `plt.scatter` will make then plot once you have the x, y coordinates. Try writing out an attempt at generating a list of `x` and `y` values and then plotting it and StackOverflow can help with specific errors you run into. Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is your question about how to determine whether or not randomly generated points lie inside the specified ellipse? or, do you already have the points and now you just need to plot them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parametric equation of an ellipse:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xm, ym = 5, -5
a, b = 5, 2.5

f, ax = plt.subplots()
# Draw an ellipse centered at xm, ym.
# Use parametric equation of an ellipse.
# t is the angle
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.plot(a * np.cos(t) + xm, b * np.sin(t) + ym)

# Generate N random points inside the ellipse
N = 100
# N random points along the angle
tr = np.random.random(N) * 2 * np.pi
# N random points along the semi major axis
ar = a * np.random.random(N)
# N random points along the semi minor axis
br = b * np.random.random(N)
xr = ar * np.cos(tr) + xm
yr = br * np.sin(tr) + ym
ax.plot(xr, yr, linestyle="none", marker=".")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```